# how to set focus to the new row in datagridview - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I don't know how to set focus point always to the new row in DataGridView in the beginning??

Answer (score 12):

To focus on the newly added row :-

```
dataGridView1.Rows(dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Selected = true;
```

or you can use this to focus on userdefine row

```
dataGridView1.Rows(Rowindex).Selected = true;
```

Ensure just the last full row is selected by using the following in your init code:

```
dataGriView1.MultiSelect = False
dataGriView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
```

Keep Coding

Answer (score 5):

```
dim NoRow As Integer = 2
me.gridTickets.CurrentCell = me.gridTickets.Rows(NoRow).Cells(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
   dgvSimpleReports.Rows(dgvSimpleReports.Rows.Count - 1).Selected = True
   dgvSimpleReports.CurrentCell = dgvSimpleReports.Rows(dgvSimpleReports.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(0)
```

Selected is not enough, because selected row only selects the row but DataGridView is not focused automatically. You need to set current row , but current row is ReadOnly, so you need to use current cell, because current cell is not ReadOnly, the code stated below should fix this problem.

Comment: this is what i've been looking for

Comment: You helped me after 4 years you posted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [CurrentCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx) property.

Comment: can give some example for me???
Because i just start to learn vb.net...
Thanks a lot, richardOD...

Comment: Modify your question with some sample code of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
If (DgViewCityMaster.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            DgViewCityMaster.Rows(0).Selected = True
        End If
```

'  Here  DGViewCityMaster is my Data Grid View

Answer (score 0):

You want to handle the RowsAdded event of your DataGridView and just select the newly added row.

```
Private Sub MyDataGridView_RowsAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles MyDataGridView.RowsAdded
     MyDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = true;
End Sub
```